# Extjs How to access the name of the chart being used by store

Tags: ajax, json, charts, extjs

I have a store being used by several charts.  I get my data remotely with an ajax call. In the php script that I link it too, I'm just going to change the parameters of my query to adjust for the different charts.

Here's my idea:  I pass the title of the chart's panel as a parameter to my php script. That'll tell me which chart it is.

How do I access the title of whatever chart the store is being used by?

```
 var my_store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
fields: ['project', 'accepted', 'rejected', 'deleted', 'undefined'],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'generate_proj.php',
    extraParams: {foo: **chart.id**},
    reader: {
    type: 'json'
    }
},
autoLoad: true,
listeners:  { 
    beforeload: function(store,operation) {
    //operation.params.foo = this.idname;
    },

    load: function(obj,records) {
    var text = Ext.decode(obj.responseText);
    Ext.each(records,function(rec) {                     
    });
    }
    }
});
```

Here's what I've done so far. Getting the name of a single chart/panel is no problem. I want **the store to be able to dynamically read the name of what's using it**.  How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere, you have some code that switches between the various charts. During that code, you could do something like

```
activeChart.getChartStore().proxy.extraParams.foo = activeChart.getId();
```

where activeChart is whatever reference you have to the chart you are about to show. Then when you load the store, it'll send the correct parameter.